# Calculating 3D coordinates of an Object with a Single Phone Camera

Tags: opencv, 3d, computer-vision, photogrammetry

I have a phone camera that’s viewing a planar object. I know the real world measurements of the object. Considering the top left corner of the object as the origin, I calculate the coordinates using the real world measurements. With the object detection algorithm I am able to get the coordinates of the detected object on the image, which is in pixels. (again going by the fact that the image's origin is on the top left hand corner). I obtain the Rotation and Translation matrix using solvepnp(). **Now is it possible (with the obtained parameters) to find the distance and the height of the object with respect to the first frame?**

Comment: Your question is unclear: 1. if you know the real world measurements of the object, then you know its height 2. if you used `solvePnP` then the norm of the resulting Translation is the distance between the object and the camera.

Comment: this might help http://codentonic.net/2013/06/08/camera-simulation/